# Dying Light: Grenades Don't Work Well

Tags: ps4, dying-light

Grenades in Dying Light don't seem to be working well. Any version of the DIY grenade or the blueprints for Kurt's bombs do what appears to be no damage, other than pushing zombies a little bit. Basic zombies took 4 grenades and didn't die, although they did die in one more hit from a melee weapon. Is this a glitch in my game? Anyone else had this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't say if it's normal or glitch but i noticed the same. However i did not find a situation were a grenade or bombs could be very useful. If you want to get through a lot of zombies you could just jump over them or just use the firecrackers to distract them. Else you could use explosives in the enviroment like those gas containers which will kill nearly zombies instantly.

Comment: I was in the Stuffed Turtle quarantine zone, and I think at the time I tried to use the grenades, there were the tougher zombies with body armor. I suppose you've answered the question, thanks.

Answer (score -2):

The only grenades I use are the freezing grenades. And I only use them on the big charging zombies. It freezes them and they stay frozen awhile so you can chop them up with your sword or whatever.